# Use OpenCV to separate the RGB image into red and green blue components and operate with these

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

I need help with OpenCV and Python.

How can I separate the green, red and blue components of an RGB image using OpenCV and Python? I also need to subdivide each of these matrices into 8x8 submatrices in order to work with them, for this I was thinking about using numpy.

The code I have so far is the following, but I am stuck with this and I am not sure if it is correct.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("4.jpg")
b = img[:,:,0]
g = img[:,:,1]
r = img[:,:,2]

divb = np.split(b,8)  # divide b in submatrices 8x8?
divg = np.split(g,8)  # divide g in submatrices 8x8?
divr = np.split(r,8)  # divide r in submatrices 8x8?

print('blue:', b)
print('red:', g)
print('green:', r)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
```

Comment: Hi Danny, before anyone answers, please expand on what your output is so far.

Comment: You are likely need to look at `skimage.util.view_as_block` [utility function](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built in numpy method to split a matrix into 8 by 8 sub-matrices. Furthermore, my main assumption with working with this problem is that you will pad the images such that the images will have width and height of dimension that is multiple 8. I think you are definitely on the right track:

```
img = cv2.imread("4.jpg")
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)

def sub_matrices(color_channel):
    matrices = []
    #How can you change how this loop iterates?
    #Also consider adding stopping conditions and/or additional loops for
    #excess parts of the image.
    for i in range(int(color_channel.shape[0]/8)):
        for j in range(int(color_channel.shape[1]/8)):
            matrices.append(color_channel[i*8:i*8 + 8, j*8:j*8+8])
    return matrices

#returns list of sub matrices
r_submatrices = sub_matrices(r)
```

The code should be pretty self-explanatory. Like I said, if the dimensions of the image is not padded such that dimensions are dimension of 8, then parts of the image will not be in any sub-matrix (for this code, specifically; change this however you need). This code can certainly be optimized (look up cache blocking) and altered for any size sub matrices (which I will leave as an exercise for you). Hope this helps.

Comment: Take a look at https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks for splitting an array into blocks of arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
img=cv2.imread("image.jpeg",1) 
    
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
R = img.copy() 
G = img.copy()
B = img.copy()

R[:,:,1] = R[:,:,2] = 0
G[:,:,0] = G[:,:,2] = 0
B[:,:,0] = B[:,:,1] = 0


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,18))
ax = fig.add_subplot(221)
bx = fig.add_subplot(222)
cx = fig.add_subplot(223)
dx = fig.add_subplot(224)

bx.imshow (R)
cx.imshow (G)
dx.imshow (B)
ax.imshow (img)



plt.show()
```